# How do I iterate bash arrays and make an SCP command efficiently?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, scp

I need to scp the files from `machineB` and `machineC` to `machineA`. I am running my below shell script from `machineA`. I have setup the ssh keys properly.

If the files are not there in `machineB`, then it should be there in `machineC`.

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly PRIMARY=/data01/primary/.
readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
readonly MAPPED_LOCATION=/bat/data/snapshot
PARTITION=(0 3 5 7 9)

dir1=/bat/data/snapshot/20131222
dir2=/bat/data/snapshot/20131222

scp david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/weekly_1980_[$el]_200003_5.data $PRIMARY || scp david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/weekly_1980_[$el]_200003_5.data $PRIMARY
```

Now my question is if you take a look into my above scp command, I have `[$el]` for now (which is wrong), I need to replace this with `PARTITION`, which means I need to iterate `PARTITION` and replace `[$el]` with each number in PARTITION.

So my scp command should look like this if I iterate `PARTITION` one by one -

```
scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_0_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_0_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.

scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_3_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_3_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.

scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_5_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_5_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.

scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_7_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_7_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.

scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_9_200003_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/bat/data/snapshot/20131222/weekly_1980_9_200003_5.data /data01/primary/.
```

**Problem Statement:-**

1. How do I iterate PARTITION in such a way, so that I can make the above SCP command?
2. And also, as you can see, I am copying the files one by one into `machineA` `/data01/primary/` folder. Is there any better way of doing this? Meaning, can I copy all the files together in one shot instead of doing it one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the PARTITION array like this

```
for el in "${PARTITION[@]}"
do
    echo "$el"
done
```

Comment: @lain: Thanks a lot. Yes it works fine. But I also have my second question... With this way, I will be doing file transfer one by one.. Is there any way, I can make this more efficient so that I can move all the files at once? Or some better way?

Comment: @TechGeeky: In what way do you want to improve efficiency? What do you have spare capacity to do ?

Comment: By efficient I meant to say, Is moving the files one by one is the only way? Can you move chunk of files in one shot? I am just trying to think whether this is the only way to move the files? Because, I need to movie atleast 420 files at a time, so it will take some time..

Comment: @TechGeeky: Surely you need to determine if your scp command is saturating your network/IO before you can decide if there is capacity to run the  commands in parallel ?

Comment: I guess, it should be fine with less load for now.. I can test it and see whether that will cause any problem or not? In any case, if I need to make this parallel then how I am going to do it? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise looking at `rsync` to complete this task, as it provides greater functionality all-round for this type of backup.  You could execute this from machineA, pointing it at the snapshot directories on B & C, and your whole snapshot directory would be mirrored.

You could then use `cron` to schedule this at set intervals.  `scp` is ideal for one-off copies, but your scenario sounds like a regular backup job.  `rsync` also communicates over standard SSH ports, so if `scp` works at present there should be no need for changes to the network, firewalls, etc.

With `rsync` you could even implement functionality to create an identical mirror on all three servers if that was required.